# Wireless suddenly ceased to work

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Until recently my wifi worked fine, but suddenly it ceased to connect to the wifi network. I can see the network on the wifi list but the connection fails. I'm pretty sure it's not a hardware issue, because when I do the same in windows (I have dual boot), everything works fine.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem?

You can find my wireless info [here](http://pastie.org/private/womfogvzuahb2qh9g0na).